# Neo4j 2.2.1 server does not start after db is generated via java code

Tags: java, neo4j

Started with a new graph.db folder. Am using embedded graph db, java and cypher query to create nodes. It seems to create the nodes successfully. Have debugged and checked the result object.

I want to now start the neo4j server to check the nodes in the browser. However, it gives the message:

> bash-4.2$ ./neo4j-community-2.2.1/bin/neo4j start
>
> **WARNING**: Max 1024
>   open files allowed, minimum of 40 000 recommended. See the Neo4j
>   manual. Starting Neo4j Server...
>
> **WARNING**: not changing user process
>   [2868]... waiting for server to be ready...... Failed to start within
>   120 seconds. Neo4j Server may have failed to start, please check the
>   logs.

I checked the console.log and message.log. But there is not error. I don't know what to read in the log files to put up here for diagnosis. Please advice.

**Console.log:**

> 2015-04-26 05:14:47.278+0000 INFO
>
> [API] Setting startup timeout to:
>   120000ms based on 120000
>
> 2015-04-26 05:14:49.700+0000 INFO
>
> [API]
>   Successfully shutdown Neo4j Server.
>
> 2015-04-26 05:15:24.684+0000 INFO
>
> [API] Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on 120000
>
> 2015-04-26 05:15:26.477+0000 INFO
>
> [API] Successfully shutdown Neo4j Server.
>
> 2015-04-26 05:19:54.699+0000 INFO
>
> [API] Setting startup timeout to:
>   120000ms based on 120000
>
> 2015-04-26 05:19:56.521+0000 INFO
>
> [API] Successfully shutdown Neo4j Server.

Where else should I look for errors? How can I get the neo4j server up?

Edit:

Checked messages.log. Text below. So looks like it is shutting down ok via the code:

```
2015-04-26 10:05:21.169+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: --- STARTED diagnostics for KernelDiagnostics:StoreFiles END ---
2015-04-26 10:05:21.356+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Database is now ready
2015-04-26 10:06:05.470+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Index population started: [:PRODUCT(id) [provider: {key=lucene, version=1.0}]]
2015-04-26 10:06:05.653+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Schema state store has been cleared.
2015-04-26 10:06:05.695+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Index population completed. Index is now online: [:PRODUCT(id) [provider: {key=lucene, version=1.0}]]
2015-04-26 10:06:05.764+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Schema state store has been cleared.
2015-04-26 10:06:18.148+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Sampled index :PRODUCT(id) with 2 unique values in sample of avg size 2 taken from index containing 2 entries
2015-04-26 10:06:46.028+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Shutdown started
2015-04-26 10:06:46.031+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Database is now unavailable
2015-04-26 10:06:46.246+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: About to rotate counts store at transaction 8 to [/home/dedhiaj/neo4j-community-2.2.1/data/graph.db/neostore.counts.db.b], from [/ho
me/dedhiaj/neo4j-community-2.2.1/data/graph.db/neostore.counts.db.a].
2015-04-26 10:06:46.250+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Successfully rotated counts store at transaction 8 to [/home/dedhiaj/neo4j-community-2.2.1/data/graph.db/neostore.counts.db.b], from
 [/home/dedhiaj/neo4j-community-2.2.1/data/graph.db/neostore.counts.db.a].
2015-04-26 10:06:47.495+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: NeoStore closed
2015-04-26 10:06:47.496+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: --- STOPPING diagnostics START ---
2015-04-26 10:06:47.497+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: --- STOPPING diagnostics END ---
```

Comment: are you sure you have called `db.shutdown()` when population of your db is about to be finished? Inspect `data/graph.db/messages.log` for more verbose log messages.

Answer (score 1):

Also increase "ulimit" of your Linux OS>