# Neo4j 2.2.2 server does not start after db is generated via java code

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am new to Neo4j. I am trying some application in Java using Neo4j 2.2.2 along with Spring Data.
I am using spring-data-neo4j (2.2.2.RELEASE) to connect the Neo4j DB. I have successfully done all CRUD opertaions using repositories in Spring Data.
But I am unable to open & view this DB in the Neo4J UI tool.
When I am trying to start Neo4J server from console, I am getting bellow error message.

```
emuser1@em02-desktop:~/Installations/neo4j-community-2.2.2/bin$ ./neo4j start
WARNING: Max 1024 open files allowed, minimum of 40 000 recommended. See the Neo4j manual.
Starting Neo4j Server...WARNING: not changing user
process [14509]... waiting for server to be ready.. Failed to start within 120 seconds.
Neo4j Server may have failed to start, please check the logs.
```

I have checked the message.log file in my DB store. It is showing below exceptions.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, /home/emuser1/Installations/neo4j-community-2.2.2/data/graph.db
at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:334) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:59) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase$1.newGraphDatabase(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:44) ~[neo4j-server-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:110) ~[neo4j-server-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:507) [neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115) [neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:203) [neo4j-server-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:117) [neo4j-server-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:69) [neo4j-server-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager@498af5c0' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:513) [neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115) [neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:330) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource@7ccdb0dd' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:513) [neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115) [neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.start(DataSourceManager.java:117) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:507) [neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader$UpgradingStoreVersionNotFoundException: 'neostore.nodestore.db' does not contain a store version, please ensure that the original database was shut down in a clean state.
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.UpgradableDatabase.checkUpgradeable(UpgradableDatabase.java:86) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreMigrator.needsMigration(StoreMigrator.java:158) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader.getParticipantsEagerToMigrate(StoreUpgrader.java:259) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader.migrateIfNeeded(StoreUpgrader.java:134) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.upgradeStore(NeoStoreDataSource.java:560) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.start(NeoStoreDataSource.java:461) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:507) [neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
... 13 common frames omitted
2015-06-20 05:41:58.344+0000 INFO [o.n.s.CommunityNeoServer]: Successfully shutdown Neo4j Server.
2015-06-20 05:41:58.345+0000 ERROR [o.n.s.CommunityBootstrapper]: Failed to start Neo Server on port [7474]
org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j Server failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@1414ed5' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:255) ~[neo4j-server-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:117) [neo4j-server-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:69) [neo4j-server-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@1414ed5' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:513) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:203) ~[neo4j-server-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
... 2 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, /home/emuser1/Installations/neo4j-community-2.2.2/data/graph.db
at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:334) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:59) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase$1.newGraphDatabase(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:44) ~[neo4j-server-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:110) ~[neo4j-server-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:507) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
... 4 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager@498af5c0' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:513) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:330) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource@7ccdb0dd' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:513) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.start(DataSourceManager.java:117) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:507) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader$UpgradingStoreVersionNotFoundException: 'neostore.nodestore.db' does not contain a store version, please ensure that the original database was shut down in a clean state.
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.UpgradableDatabase.checkUpgradeable(UpgradableDatabase.java:86) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreMigrator.needsMigration(StoreMigrator.java:158) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader.getParticipantsEagerToMigrate(StoreUpgrader.java:259) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader.migrateIfNeeded(StoreUpgrader.java:134) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.upgradeStore(NeoStoreDataSource.java:560) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.start(NeoStoreDataSource.java:461) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:507) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
... 13 common frames omitted
```

Can anyone please help me. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

**Note:** I have same question as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29874200/neo4j-2-2-1-server-does-not-start-after-db-is-generated-via-java-code). But there is no satisfying answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some version confusion. Spring Data Neo4j 2.2.2 works with Neo4j 1.9 or so. SDN 3.0 with Neo4j 2.0 and only SDN 3.3.1 (to be released) with Neo4j 2.2.2.
SDN 3.3.0 works with Neo4j 2.1.x

That's why it asks you for the `allow_store_upgrade=true` configuration setting in `conf/neo4j.properties`.

But I recommend to upgrade your SDN project to SDN 3.3.0 then reimport your data and still upgrade from Neo4j 2.1 to 2.2 but at least you will have labels and schema indexes.

Comment: Thank you very much Michael. Can you please do me a favor by suggesting the resources from where can I get the SDN related information for further development.

Comment: To clarify, you mean to *not* upgrade to Neo4j 2.2, because it isn't supported until SDN 3.3.1, correct?